# Difference between the vertex program and Merge Message part in Pregel API in GraphX

Tags: spark-graphx

I am new to GraphX and I do not understand the Vertex Program and Merge Message part in Pregel API. Do not do they the same thing ?
For example what is the difference between Vertex Program and Merge Message part in the following Pregel code taken from the Spark website?

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
// Import random graph generation library
import org.apache.spark.graphx.util.GraphGenerators
// A graph with edge attributes containing distances
val graph: Graph[Long, Double] =
  GraphGenerators.logNormalGraph(sc, numVertices = 100).mapEdges(e => e.attr.toDouble)
val sourceId: VertexId = 42 // The ultimate source
// Initialize the graph such that all vertices except the root have distance infinity.
val initialGraph = graph.mapVertices((id, _) => if (id == sourceId) 0.0 else Double.PositiveInfinity)
val sssp = initialGraph.pregel(Double.PositiveInfinity)(
  (id, dist, newDist) => math.min(dist, newDist), **// Vertex Program**
  triplet => {  // Send Message
    if (triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr < triplet.dstAttr) {
      Iterator((triplet.dstId, triplet.srcAttr + triplet.attr))
    } else {
      Iterator.empty
    }
  },
  (a,b) => math.min(a,b) **// Merge Message**
  )
println(sssp.vertices.collect.mkString("\n"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For one thing, the `mergeMsg` part has no access to the context of any `Vertex` -- it just takes individual messages and creates a single message. That message in turn gets sent to the `vprog` as a single message.

So, the `vprog` has no access to individual messages, just the *total* (whatever that means). And the `mergeMsg` can only take two messages and create one message. `mergeMessage` happens until there is only one message left -- the *total* -- which as I said gets passed to `vprog`.